# Hold RMB after button and click

Tags: autohotkey

I can't figure this out.

I'm trying to accomplish something like this:

1. Press a GUI button
2. When I click the mouse next hold the RMB
3. When I click again release the RMB

Current work:

```
    Toggle=0
    GUI, Add, Button, w50 h50, Nbutton
    GUI, Show, x50 y50
    return

    ButtonNButton:
    {
        Toggle:=!Toggle
    }

    if GetKeyState("LButton","P")
        if (Toggle == 1)
            MsgBox, Do
            Toggle:=!Toggle
    return
```

Comment: It's unclear to me exactly what you want to do, particularly in steps 5 & 6. However, you probably are going to want to use [SetTimer](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm) to poll for the LButton press.

Comment: I have edited the question to be more straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

This should work to accomplish what you want.

Note that right now, this example script is limited to only work in Notepad. You should update the script to target whatever program/game/window you want the hotkey to be active in.

```
Toggle := 0
GUI, Add, Button, w50 h50, Nbutton
GUI, Show, x50 y50
return

ButtonNButton:
    Toggle:=!Toggle


    ; Update this line to match whatever window you want the hotkey active
    ; in, or delete this line to make the hotkey active everywhere.
    Hotkey, IfWinActive, ahk_class Notepad


    if Toggle
    {
        Hotkey, ~*LButton Up, RBSwitch, On
    }
    else
    {
        if GetKeyState("RButton") ;release RButton when hotkey is disabled
            Send {RButton Up}
        Hotkey, ~*LButton Up, RBSwitch, Off
    }
RETURN


RBSwitch:
    if GetKeyState("RButton")
        Send {RButton Up}
    else
        Send {RButton Down}
RETURN
```